# How to filter data of blogs to not add empty blogs or blogs with empty titles

Tags: javascript, filter, blogs

Here's the controller:

import API from '../scripts/api.js'
class Controller {

```
constructor(model, view) {
    this.model = model
    this.view = view
    this.author=window.location.search.substr(10), 
    this.view.handleShowForm()
}


//a function to  get the  data from the api
fetch() {
  API.readAll('https://blog-server-rbk.herokuapp.com/api/blogs',function (data) {
    console.log('data: data sent',data)
    this.model.addBlogs(data) ;


})
}
```

and the model class with the method addBlogs, the problem is there,that should add blogs to the state

```
  class Model {
constructor() {
    //a state of the model 
    this.blogs = []
}
 

//this function should filter to not add empty blogs
addBlogs(blogs) {
    blogs.filter(element => element.body.length==0 || element.title.length==0)
    this.blogs = blogs;
}
```

}

export default Model

Comment: Filter function does not mutate the original array, try instead to assign the result of the function to the this.blog variable